# How can I shrink the disk INSIDE VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, partitioning, osx-yosemite

I created a virtual disk using WindowsXP inside VirtualBox, the host is OSX.
Initially I created the disk 20Gb, in 2 partitions, each of 10Gb.
Because I did not need it, I dropped the 2nd partition, which is now
reported as empty space.

How can I shrink the disk to only the 1st partition, saving 10Gb
and shrinking the .vdi too?

Comment: Did you read [this page](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661) or [this page](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17512)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all do a **backup of your image disk**: it's always wise and safe.
Then you can use `VBoxManage modifyhd` with this syntax

```
VBoxManage modifyhd <absolute path to file> --resize <size in MB>
```

In your case I think the commandline should be

```
VBoxManage modifyhd <absolute path with the name and extension> --resize 10240
```

Reference :

- The [8.23. VBoxManage modifyhd](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) of the Virtualbox Manual.
- This page from the [virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661)

Comment: The command: "VBoxManage modifyhd /E/VirtualBox/Kaibab.vdi --resize 10400" failed with: Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet! I guess my disk was fixed at creation. I think I'm going to create it all over again to the right size. Thanks anyway. ;JOOP!